# How to use Schedulers.trampoline() inRxJava

Tags: rx-java

Since `Schedulers.trampoline()` makes the job work on the current thread,
I cannot find the difference between the case with `Schedulers.trampoline()` and the case without Schedulers settings.

Using `Schedulers.trampoline()`:

```
Observable.from(1, 2, 3)
    .observeOn(Schedulers.trampoline())
    .subscribe(System.out::println)
```

Not Using Schedulers:

```
Observable.from(1, 2, 3)
    .subscribe(System.out::println)
```

I think that above codes act the same.
I really wonder why `Schedulers.trampoline()` exists in RxJava's API.

In what situation, should I use `Schedulers.trampoline()`?

Comment: https://medium.com/@I_Love_Coding/rxjava-schedulers-trampoline-use-cases-283f6649cbf#.llbctjqf5

Comment: @R. Zagórski, this article does not help at all, because you would not use the scheduler with observeOn/ subscribeOn. What would be, if you would like one thread, but this thread should run not on the main? For this use-case Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1) woulde be better.

Comment: I saw some articles like this and I wonder what would be diffrerent from without `observeOn()`. Also, I find some articles which show the difference between `Schedulers.trampoline()` and `Schedulers.immediate()`  by using Workers.  However, I could not find the information how to use `Schedulers.trampoline()` with `observeOn()`. Any way, Thank you for the information!!

Comment: There is a good example in the book 'Reactive Programming with RxJava' (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920042228.do). I would recommand buying this book if you are serious about RxJava

Comment: Well.. OK! I clicked to buy this one!! I knew about this book but I wonder whether I should wait for RxJava 2.x edition. But the reputation is so good, so it might be worth to buy this book. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you would not gain any benefits from using the scheduler in observeOn/ subscribeOn. You would use the Worker from the scheduler to schedule work after work.

Please have a look at the example. I am using RxJava2-RC5

```
@Test
public void trampoline() throws Exception {
        Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.trampoline();
        Scheduler.Worker worker = scheduler.createWorker();

        Runnable r1 = () -> {
            System.out.println("Start: r1");
            System.out.println("End: r1");
        };

        Runnable r2 = () -> {
            System.out.println("Start: r2");
            worker.schedule(r1);
            System.out.println("End: r2");
        };

        worker.schedule(r2);
}
```

Output:

> Start: r2  End: r2  Start: r1  End: r1

The trampoline worker comes in handy, if you are scheduling work recursively, because you would not get and StackOverFlow.

The example was rephrased to RxJava from introtorx (http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html)

Comment: Thank you for the information! I'm glad to know that the `Schedulers.trampoline()` were not for `observeOn()` or `subscribeOn()`. To me, this scheduler can be seen as the utility for concurrency programming, I guess.

Comment: So, In other words, is this for enqueue task?

Comment: @dicarlomagnus, it depends whether you use Scheduler or Scheduler.Worker. If you schedule work via Scheduler, the runnable will be executed immediately with delay=0 and will block calling thread for delayed time and then execute the runnable. The Worker does things differently. A task, which has no delay will be appended to a queue (PriorityBlockingQueue) and the queue will be drained (trampolining).  A delayed Worker-task is executed by timed sleeps, which blocks the main Thread (see SleepingRunnable)

Answer (score 4):

There is another usage for `Schedulers.trampoline()`, please check the following:

```
println("Current thread: ${Thread.currentThread()}")
Observable.interval(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.trampoline())
    .subscribe{
        println("$it thread: ${Thread.currentThread()}")
    }
println("This never will be reached")
```

If the one runs the code on the main thread then the result will be something like this:

```
Current thread: Thread[main,5,main]
0 thread: Thread[main,5,main]
1 thread: Thread[main,5,main]
2 thread: Thread[main,5,main]
3 thread: Thread[main,5,main]
4 thread: Thread[main,5,main]
5 thread: Thread[main,5,main]
...
```

And `println("This never will be reached")` will be reached never.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but from the docs:

> The immediate scheduler is not present in 2.x. It was frequently
>   misused and didn't implement the Scheduler specification correctly
>   anyway; it contained blocking sleep for delayed action and didn't
>   support recursive scheduling at all. Use Schedulers.trampoline()
>   instead.

This would imply your accepted answer may be wrong. See
https://medium.com/@I_Love_Coding/rxjava-schedulers-trampoline-use-cases-283f6649cbf
that says:

> All jobs that subscribe on trampoline() will be queued and executed
>   one by one.

and actually shows an example like

```
 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline())
```

Comment: I dont think that your source is a credible source. Lets have a look at an explanation from one, who implemented it: "The trampoline-scheduler [...] also schedules tasks in the same thread, effectively blocking. However, as opposed to immediate, the upcoming task is executed when all previously scheduled tasks complete. immediate invokes a given task right away, whereas trampoline waits for the current task to finish. Trampoline is a pattern in functional programming that allows implementing recursion without infinitely growing the call stack" -- Reactive Programming with RxJava

Answer (score 0):

It comes handy for tests too. In that case you do not use the scheduler directly but inject (or set or hand into your class via constructor) an object (or provider) into your class that holds the scheduler(s) you need. You use this object holding your scheduler in `subscribeOn` and `observeOn`. 
When testing then you inject (or set or hand into) `trampoline()` instead so your tests all run on the same thread.